# Fill color of a single point in a ScatterSeries

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, oxyplot

So, I have tried to create a `ScatterSeries` using **OxyPlot under Xamarin.Forms** for which I want a point to be filled when a user interacts with it.

The plot itself is rendered just fine, and interaction *seemingly* does too.

The problem is that once I click on a point, it is not *at first* filled using the `SelectionColor` of the `PlotModel`. I have to drag the canvas in order for it to update, whereafter the specific point is updated and filled with the `SelectionColor`.

I instantiate the `PlotModel` like so:

```
var model = new PlotModel()
{  
    SelectionColor = OxyColors.Red,
    // ...
};
```

Hereafter I instantiate the my `ScatterSeries`:

```
var scatterSeries = new ScatterSeries()
{
    SelectionMode = SelectionMode.Single,
    // ...
};
```

Next I create a `List` of `ScatterPoint`s:

```
var scatterPoints = new List<ScatterPoint>
{
    new ScatterPoint(0, 4),
    // ...
};
```

Lastly, I listen to the `TouchStarted` event of the `ScatterSeries`:

```
scatterSeries.TouchStarted += (sender, e) =>
{
    var xCoordinate = e.Position.X;
    var yCoordinate = e.Position.Y;

    var screenPoint = new ScreenPoint(xCoordinate, yCoordinate);

    var point = lineSeries.GetNearestPoint(screenPoint, false);
    var index = (int)point.Index;
    scatterSeries.SelectItem(index);

    // I expect it to refresh and update the PlotModel here:
    model.InvalidatePlot(true); 

    e.Handled = true;
};
```

As mentioned this seems to work fine, except for that the `PlotModel` is not updated immediately with the `SelectionColor` - I have to drag the canvas before it updates.

Any ideas?

Comment: For now, I have [created an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/issues/288). Awaiting response.